# Sort files on timestamp till milliseconds in Linux

Tags: linux, file, ls, milliseconds

I am trying to pick up files from a secondary  server via SFTP and then processing the files. The files are created on secondary server in less than 1 second and as a result all the files have same timestamp for creation.Lets suppose 4 files (1.txt , 2.txt, 3.txt and 4.txt) are created on secondary server in the same orders. However when I run  ls -ltr command on  the server , I get out put as follows:

[image]

Also when I tried to sort files based on time till milliseconds using the command ls --full-time -ltr , I got the following output:

[image]

The above output is wrong as file 1 was created before remaining files. Can somebody please help on how to get the correct sorted list  here.

Comment: The files all have the same timestamp, how can any tool know that file 1 was created before the others ? (Note also that linux does not store the time when the file is created, it shows the time the file was last modified.

Comment: Don't misuse a filesystem as a serial communication channel.  You might was well ask how to tell the fractional part of an integral value.  "Hey, this hammer doesn't do a good job of fixing my leaking toilet."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since, the timestamps are same even up to milliseconds, I think the only way to sort these properly is using inode of each file. I think this solution should be able to work in your scenario.

Here is my example interaction, I created files 1, 3, 4, 2 in this sequence at the same time.
Using `ls --full-time -lt` doesn't work. But using `ls --full-time -i | sort -u` lists these files in the order they were created.
[image]

Comment: Thanks Saeed. Lets suppose you create files in order 1 ,3 , 4 and 2. The the above command fails!!

Comment: I've updated my answer with a new command, which I think should work for your scenario. :)

Comment: Thanks Saeed Yasin !!